# Add library permanently for all future projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to permanently and automagically have a library added for all my future projects?  (in Visual Studio 2008)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have a look at [Project Templates](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CustomWizard11292005004112AM/CustomWizard.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Matthew has the [real answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575113/add-library-permanently-for-all-future-projects/1575131#1575131) for this - but as a stop-gap; don't forget the "Recent" tab on the "Add References" dialog. In many ways it is a shame that it doesn't *default* to this tab. This tab makes adding your common libraries pretty painless (once that lethargic dialog opens).

Comment: Wow. I had to actually check this out, I don't normally use the Recent tab so I didn't even notice it was even there.